# Infragistics WebDatePicker: calendar dropdown broken in iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net, calendar, infragistics

We're making a big web form for customers, and it's got half a dozen date fields, for which we are using the Infragistics WebDatePicker control (in asp.net 4.6).  They work fine (though applying validators to them was a lot of work) except when we try them on an iPad.  In Safari for iOS, tapping on the button to drop down the calendar causes it to flash momentarily and then disappear.  No such problem on an android device, so far as we've seen.  The problem isn't just on our new page, but on all our old ones that also use the control.

Edit: the problem happens in Safari but not in Chrome.

Has anybody encountered this?  Has any work been put into resolving this issue?  Or are we the only ones seeing it?

Googling seems to come up empty, and Infragistics' support request page appears to currently be inaccessible.

I'm hoping this doesn't come down to finding a way to instrument 50 javascript events on an ipad.

---

To update, here is the exact case where we're seeing the problem:

- device: iPad Air 2 64gb (model MH2M2LL/A)
- system: iOS 8.4.1
- browser: Mobile Safari 600.1.4
- infragistics version: 15.2 for asp.net 4.5
- example site: http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet/editors/date-picker

...yup, it's failing in Infragistics' own demo page.  (Use the second "view sample" link.)

It doesn't fail every time: sometimes the first click after page load succeeds, but the ones after it all fail.

---

Second update: Infragistics has entered this in their bug tracker as #216122.

Comment: I actually did manage to monitor events in Safari, and what I learned is that tapping the calendar button is producing touchstart, touchend, mousemove, and mousedown.  The absence of mouseup is a bit suspicious.

Comment: It appears that something is yanking the focus in such a way that the mouseup is heard by a different control than the mousedown is.  Of course it's too late by the time mouseup happens -- the real problem is the focus change.

Comment: The problem ended up going away by itself.  Now we'll never know what it was.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this with the latest SR for 15.1 and could not reproduce the described issue. In order to receive better support, I suggest you to open a ticket for this issue trough the Infragistics site. What is more, it will be best if you add all the related environment details (like Infragistics product version you are using), and attach a simple code sample in order for the Infragistics Dev Support to reproduce the described behavior.

Comment: I might have opened an Infragistics ticket if your ticket-opening page worked.

Comment: This is ironic: I got the support ticket page to load by browsing it on the iPad.  I then was unable to submit a ticket.  It kept saying "there was a problem while submitting".  Looks like I'm gonna have to use email.

Comment: Now I have a case open, but the url supplied with it to see its status won't open.  Connection closed at the server end, it says.